# Pipe command to specific cmd.exe

Tags: batch-file, command-line

So I've written a .bat file (later on refered to as the 2nd one) to backup files every night and then weekly offsite to ensure the files aren't lost. However I realized that a process may be running and currently editing the files so it'd be best to shut down the process and then start it again once the backup is done.

Now, the main problem is this: The process is another batch file running under cmd.exe. There is also a java.exe command window that is created in conjunction with the cmd.exe, and entering the stop into either the cmd.exe or java.exe windows produces the same and the process will stop their process safely. With that in mind I've tried the following commands (minus the *s),

```
echo stop | cmd.exe
echo stop | java.exe
```

but what I find is that the cmd.exe pipe is just sending the command to the command window opened by the 2nd batch file. Meanwhile the java.exe command returns an error in the 2nd batch file on how that the proper parameters weren't used.

That being said my main question is this:

**Is it possible to pipe commands to specific cmd windows, if so how?**

Comment: If you converted your 2nd bat file to an exe, you could use `taskkill`

Comment: You can set a `window title` in the java batch file and use a VBS script with `sendkeys` to type into the cmd window with that window title.

Comment: @Monacraft I'm aware of the taskkill command, but that is a brunt way of stopping a task, especially when the stop command could be typed in and it'd shutdown safely.

Comment: @foxidriv I'll look into using a VBS script for that portion, perhaps the rest of the script as well if that's possible. I'm not the most familiar with vbs console applications.